# Rails 5 is adding a "." to a link_to path instead of a "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying out Rails 5 and have come across something weird. Everywhere that I've googled says that my code is right. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My view code:

```
<% provide(:title, "View all Users") %>

<% @users = User.all %>

<ul>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% @user = user %>
    <li><%= link_to user.name, users_path(@user) %><%= user.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Spits out html:

```
<a href="/users.3">boop boop</a>
```

Notice that the path is using a dot instead of a forward slash.

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue is the `users_path(@user)`. You have an extra `s` there, try `user_path(@user)` or even better try `@user`

I would write that line as `<li><%= link_to user.name, @user %><%= user.name %></li>`

Rails is smart enough to understand that linking an `object` means you want to go to the `show` page for the `object`

Comment: This was the correct answer. It's hard to wrap my head around the extra stuff that Rails is doing for me with regards to Type/Single (Users/User). Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @ramijames anytime! I actually ran into this issue myself and banged my head against it for about 2 days. So one thing you will run into issue wise with rails is whether something is plural or not, when in doubt double check if you have or need an s at the point of error. I am not 100% sure what it is doing, but I believe it things you are trying to pass extra params to the controller, but because you didn't specify the name of parameters it thinks that you want to be able to call a different format (such as xmo, json, etc)

Comment: It's frustrating because I actually started with singular and it wasn't rendering for whatever reason. I must have almost had it and then went down the wrong path. Live and learn. Thanks again.

Comment: @ramijames anytime, our mistakes are what helps us understand the black magic of rails. It is a wonderful black magic, but it can be dangerous lol